# One or more validation errors occurred. Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an api call that just isn't working but it looks correct to me. I am getting

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-d236b384c74f095e171ed2e12c33ee4b-efc6481d1abaae86-00",
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "The value 'filter-data' is not valid."
        ]
    }
}
```

as the response in postman with `400 Bad Request` as a status

```
public class PlantPollutionController : ApiBaseController<PlantPollution>
{
  //... ctor and other methods that work
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("filter-data")]
    public IEnumerable<PlantPollution> FilterData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 // other methods that work
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiBaseController<T> : ControllerBase
    where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
 //other methods that work
}
```

So I don't ever get to the Constructor here.

And this is what I am seeing in the console

> [06:08:52 WRN] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
> [06:08:52 INF] Executing endpoint
> 'RecordKeeping.Api.Controllers.API.PlantPollutionController.Get
> (RecordKeeping.Api)' [06:08:52 INF] Route matched with {action =
> "Get", controller = "PlantPollution"}. Executing controller action
> with signature RecordKeeping.Models.PlantPollution Get(Int32) on
> controller RecordKeeping.Api.Controllers.API.Pl antPollutionController
> (RecordKeeping.Api). [06:08:52 INF] Executing BadRequestObjectResult,
> writing value of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails'. [06:08:52 INF]
> Executed action
> RecordKeeping.Api.Controllers.API.PlantPollutionController.Get
> (RecordKeeping.Api) in 347.8816ms [06:08:52 INF] Executed endpoint
> 'RecordKeeping.Api.Controllers.API.PlantPollutionController.Get
> (RecordKeeping.Api)' [06:08:52 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET
> http://localhost:5000/api/PlantPollution/filter-data - - - 400 -
> application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 504.5763ms

Would anyone know what could be causing this strange error, what validation is being called?

**Edit**
and example of one that works:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{plantId}/add-zeros/{endDate}")]
public IEnumerable<PlantPollution> AddZeros(int plantId, DateTime endDate)
{
      return _plantPollutionService.AddZeros(plantId, endDate);
}
```

Comment: Can you add one example of one of the methods that _do_ work?

Comment: yeah, I've tried both ways.

Comment: sure, I added one.

Comment: I once had an incident, where routes would collide. I am just not sure if it was in a Controller or in a set of Azure Functions.... I ended up in a "wrong" method because one of the uri elements was interpreted as id instead of fix value. Like it was GET /some/{id} and PUT /some/dependend/{id} and it would always tell me PUT /some/{id} is unknown ...  not sure about the exact routes any more, that was quite some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I've finally figured out what the issue was. There was a combination of things going on here. The first thing was that I had a method `public T Get<T>(int id)...` in the base class. Which was being called instead of `public IEnumerable<PlantPollution> FilterData()...`. The reason this was happening was that the IDE was cashing the previous build in Release mode and not removing the cache when I ran the application. The fix was simple, change from Release to Debug in the IDE.

I hope this helps the next person.